# add guzzlehttp to codeignator

Tags: codeigniter, guzzle

I got the following error:

```
Message: Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found
```

I've added the require to composer like the following:

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0"
},
```

and in `application config/config.php`:

```
$config['composer_autoload'] = TRUE;
```

but it can't be added, I have no vendor/autoload.php file available nor vendor folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this issue was solved by copied a ready exist (vendor + autload.php ) to main application folder along with guzzlehttp